# How to override Sublime Text 3 Package's (CSS3) completion syntax

Tags: sublimetext3

I'm using the [CSS3](https://github.com/y0ssar1an/CSS3) package with Sublime Text 3.

I'm trying to override the behaviour when typing a CSS property. For example, given the following:

```
body {
  | <- insertion point
}
```

If I type `background` and press tab, the result will be `background:`, which I what I want.

If I type `background:`, the moment I type the colon, the line changes to `background: ;`, with the insertion point before the semi-colon. I don’t want this, as I always type a space after the colon myself, ending up with two spaces there. I don't want to retrain my muscle memory as all my other editing environments don't add the space automatically.

I would really like to figure out how to override this completion behaviour.

I've tried editing the `completions/properties.py` file inside the CSS3 package but that does not seem to be the source of this completion. Unfortunately I don't know enough about how ST packages are put together to figure this out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The completions that are coming from `completions/properties.py` are used by the package's `on_query_completions` handler, which is what's used by Sublime to populate the autocompletion popup. As such, modifying the contents there (and restarting Sublime so the package reloads) would alter what gets offered in the autocomplete popup (or what can be automatically chosen as the best completion, in the correct circumstances).

```py
    ("background", "background: ${1};"),
```

This specifies that the autocomplete trigger of `background` should expand out to the name of the property followed by a colon and a space, and the cursor is left at `${1}`, so something like `back`<kbd>Tab</kbd> expands out to `background: |;`; this is the place to modify if you want to add to or modify these kinds of completions.

On the other hand, the issue you're having is that pressing <kbd>:</kbd> is what triggers the space to be inserted. This isn't actually something that's autocomplete related at all, though that's not entirely obvious from looking at it.

If you turn on command logging (`View > Show Console`, `sublime.log_commands(True)`) and follow your steps above, when you press <kbd>:</kbd> you see this in the console:

```
command: insert_snippet {"contents": ": $0;"}
```

That's an indication that there's a key binding in place that's doing this for you. Using `View Package File` from the command palette and filtering with `css3 keymap` will let you open `CSS3/Default.sublime-keymap`, where the first key binding is what's doing this:

```
    { "keys": [":"], "command": "insert_snippet", "args": {"contents": ": $0;"}, "context":
        [
            { "key": "setting.auto_match_enabled", "operator": "equal", "operand": true },
            { "key": "selection_empty", "operator": "equal", "operand": true, "match_all": true },
            { "key": "selector", "operator": "equal", "operand": "meta.declaration-list.css, meta.at-rule.color-profile.block.css, meta.at-rule.counter-style.block.css, meta.at-rule.font-face.block.css, meta.font-feature-type-block.css, meta.at-rule.font-palette-values.block.css, meta.at-rule.page.block.css -meta.page-margin-box.css, meta.at-rule.viewport.block.css", "match_all": true },
            { "key": "selector", "operator": "not_equal", "operand": "meta.selector.css", "match_all": true },
            { "key": "following_text", "operator": "regex_contains", "operand": "^(?:\t| |\\}|$)", "match_all": true }
        ]
    },
```

The `context` applied to this binding ensures that it triggers in this particular situation, and it's manually triggering the `insert_snippet` command to insert the space and semicolon for you.

In order to stop it from doing this, copy that binding from this file into your own key bindings file and change the `contents` to not include the space that you don't want.

I don't use this package, but based on the scope selectors in the `context` this can trigger in a few different instances and not just in this one; in all cases it would cause the insertion of the space as well.

If your muscle memory always inserts the space in response to entering a `:` then that's not a big deal; if it is then you would need to alter the copied binding to change the `selector` context lines so that they only match when you're editing a property. That would cause Sublime to select your key binding in that case but to fall back to the one in the package in other cases.

Comment: Yes! What an awesome answer – thank you. That `sublime.log_commands(True)` tip will come in handy.

Comment: huge answer, spent hours looking for a solution.  Thank you.